# How to handle null response for json object

Tags: android, json

I get a JSON response as

```
{
"edges": [],
"nodes": []
}
```

how to check if the objects has null values and handle the case??

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(line);
JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("edges");
if(jArray.length()!=0)
{    
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  x.add((float) json_data.getInt("x"));
  y.add((float) json_data.getInt("y"));
end
```

This retrurns me : org.json.JSONException: end of input at character 0 of

Comment: Does that exception throw at this line, by any chance? `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(line);` I suspect you aren't parsing the response you think you are, since the exception message indicates you tried to parse an empty string. The parsing happens on your first line; the rest is fluff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check as:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(line);
if (jobj.getJSONArray("edges").length() == 0) {

    System.out.println("JSONArray is null");      
 }
 else{
      System.out.println("JSONArray is not null");
      //parse your string here         
     }
```

Comment: what error it's showing?  because you have two json Array inside JSONObject so JSONObject is not null. now you only need to check JSONArray is empty or not

Comment: org.json.JSONException: end of input at character 0 of

Comment: @user1494754 : if still facing same issue then check jArray.length() > -1 because if it's empty then it contain less then zero element . as you known also indexing start from 0

Comment: Nope.No luck.It did the same

Comment: @user1494754 : you have tried `jArray.length() > -1` condition ?

Comment: @user1494754 : why you are saying it's not working. because it's working perfectly on my end

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
String jsonString = "{ "edges": [], "nodes": [] }";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

if( jsonObject.isNull("edges") == false) {
//do sth
}

if( jsonObject.isNull("nodes") == false) {
//do sth
}
```

you can also check if you have some particular key in your json by jsonObject.has("edges")

you are passing some \line\ variable to the JSONObject constructor. make sure that this variable contains your whole json string like this one in my example and not something like 
 "{" or ' "edges": [] ' maybe the problem is in your json source like dokkaebi suggested in comment

Comment: are u sure this will work because isNull just check key is exist in JsonObject or not

Comment: isNull check if key exist or if it have null value
has() method checks only some key existence

this is what documentation says "Determine if the value associated with the key is null or if there is no value."

Answer (score 2):

try this on. I am showing example only for only one array depending on flag value you can show proper error message or on success you can bind parsed data to UI component.

```
String impuStr = "{\"edges\": [],\"nodes\": []}";
```

String flag = serverResponse(impuStr);

private String serverResponse(String jsonStr)
    {
        String flag = "success";

```
    JSONObject jobj;
    try {
        jobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

        JSONArray jArrayEdges = jobj.getJSONArray("edges");
        if(jArrayEdges != null && jArrayEdges.length() > 0)
        {    
          for(int i=0;i<jArrayEdges.length();i++)
          {
              JSONObject json_data = jArrayEdges.getJSONObject(i);
              // process data here
          }
         }else
             flag = "edges_list_empty";

    } catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        flag = "failure";
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple java rules. Check if the array is empty, if the array does not exist and you try to get it, it just returns null. Just handle it. Don't continue parsing if you know its going to fail. Just exist gracefully.

```
if (myObj != null)
{
  ... process
}
```